# Is there a way to find the highest 90 day total value for any 90 day period in the last year?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm thinking the only way to do it is to sum the values between (today - 365) and (today -65 + 90) then move on by 1 day each time, but that would be impractical. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one row on each day:

```
select top (1) t.*
from (select t.*, sum(x) over (order by date rows between 89 preceding and current row) as sum_90
      from t
     ) t
order by sum_90 desc;
```